# How can I use the latest pre-release version of Cake

Tags: c#, powershell, cakebuild

I want to make use of some of the new features that are available in the soon to be released version of Cake.  What modifications do I have to make to the bootstrapper and packages.config file in order to download the latest pre-release version, rather than the latest released version.

Answer (score 1):

By default, when restoring packages through the Cake Bootstrapper, a default source of nuget.org is used to locate packages.  Cake only pushes released versions to nuget.org, and instead pushes pre-release versions of Cake to it's MyGet Feed.  You can find out more information about how Cake uses MyGet [here](http://cakebuild.net/blog/2016/08/how-does-cake-use-myget).

In order to consume the latest pre-release version of Cake within your build script, a modification to the default bootstrapper will be required.

Assuming you are using the latest bootstrapper from [here](https://github.com/cake-build/resources) then this is the [line](https://github.com/cake-build/resources/blob/develop/build.ps1#L168) that you are going to need to change.

From this:

`` $NuGetOutput = Invoke-Expression "&`"$NUGET_EXE`" install -ExcludeVersion -OutputDirectory `"$TOOLS_DIR`"" ``

to this:

`` $NuGetOutput = Invoke-Expression "&`"$NUGET_EXE`" install -ExcludeVersion -PreRelease -OutputDirectory `"$TOOLS_DIR`" -Source https://www.myget.org/F/cake/api/v3/index.json" ``

Or, if you are running on Linux/OSX, you would need to change this [line](https://github.com/cake-build/resources/blob/develop/build.sh#L80) of your build.sh from this:

`mono "$NUGET_EXE" install -ExcludeVersion`

to this:

`mono "$NUGET_EXE" install -ExcludeVersion -PreRelease -Source https://www.myget.org/F/cake/api/v3/index.json"`

On top of that, you will also need to update your packages.config file in the tools folder, to specify which pre-release version you would like to use.  At the time of writing, the latest version available is `0.18.0-alpha0105` so you would need the following:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
    <package id="Cake" version="0.18.0-alpha0105" />
</packages>`